# how to render <Aura:html as first class object in lightning?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

What should this tag render ? Is anything missing this tag as

```
<aura:html tag="div" body="Iam inside  div tag " />
```

as per sfdc documentation https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_html.htm 
this is first class object in lightning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like any other component in aura, the `body` attribute accepts array of Aura.Component instances(`Aura.Component[]`).

In our case [aura:html](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_aura_html.htm) expects `body` to be of type `Aura.Component[]`.I think it is ignored because of the type mismatch.

You can set the aura:html's body attribute in the markup implictly by doing this:

```
<aura:html tag="div">Hello World</aura:html>
```

Anything within the start tag and end tag be it a custom component, aura/ui/lightning namespaced component is considered as the `body` of that particular component.

Comment: Thanks Praveen and crmprogdev, Yes it worked as Praveen suggested.  Appreciate response. However, body="<b> hello</b>" as attribute doesnt work. So body is - any valid HTML enlcosed within <aura:html> tag and accepts button as well  which is little surprising behavior e.g. <aura:html tag="div"><input type="text" value="hello"></input></aura:html>

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it should render anything. Your markup needs to conform to strict [XHTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/) and it doesn't appear to me that what you've posted does. While you've added a body tag, you've not put in any kind of `<p>` tag or other formatting to encapsulate the text. In fact, I don't believe the body tag would be necessary. If it were, it would come BEFORE the div tag.

Comment: It will render only if you pass value which matches the type of  `body` attribute.